# Regular Expression needed to parse out the values of several variables

Tags: .net, regex

I am trying to retrieve a list of all the variable values from the following example:

```
JobName :: Variable1 = 1 | Variable2 = 2 | Variable3 = 3
```

I would like help returning values 1 2 and 3 from the above variables

I am trying to make the following work but am so far quite unsuccessful! Not sure how to correctly use the OR and AND symbols in a regular expression.

```
(<?<=\s*=\s*).+ | \n
```

Basically the regular expression should match whatever comes after the EQUAL sign and continue matching up to the PIPE and or END OF THE LINE.

Another example:

```
JobName :: Variable1 = 123456 234567 | Variable2 = asdf q s | Variable3 = as123!@#/*()
```

Regex would return:  123456 234567 , asdf q s , as123!@#/*()

Please note: I just need to return what is BETWEEN [= and |] OR [= and \n]

Comment: I am assuming you want to match Variable1, Variable2, ... , VariableN.  Not just 3 variables, correct?

Comment: @WillC. Correct. i was just giving 3 variables as an example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
        string a = "JobName :: Variable1 = 123456 234567 | Variable2 = asdf q s | Variable3 = as123!@#/*()";

        MatchCollection mc = Regex.Matches(a, "Variable.+?=(.+?)([|]|$)");
        foreach (Match item in mc)
        {
            string res = item.Result("$1");
        }
```

or you can even skip "Variable" and just use `"=(.+?)([|]|$)"` as pattern

Comment: Thank you. Any way to use =(.+?)([|]|$) without including the "=" and "|" in the result? I just need to return what is BETWEEN [= and |] OR [= and \n]

Comment: @ThePracticalSyde have you tried it? It returns exactly what you need

Comment: @ThePracticalSyde be sure to check not the Match, but Result!

Comment: Heres the problem, i am using an automation utility to parse the text (using a regular expression) It will just return the matches back to me. Does not allow me to check the result.

Comment: @ThePracticalSyde which utility and how does it return matches?

Comment: Its an automation utility called WinAutomation. It returns matches as a list of text values. For instance, using your second regex (=(.+?)([|]|$)) returns to me: {"= 2 |", "= 3"}. It returns the values i need, just with the = and | symbols.

Comment: @ThePracticalSyde it's impossible to get matches as you wish. You will have to loop through the list of returned matches and trim = and | for example by using `Substring` function

Comment: Ok. I think you have given me enough to go off of. I will just remove the "=" and "|" symbols from my results. Thanks so much for your help.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know about .net, but I tried this in ruby and worked perfectly:

```
=\s([^\|]*)\s?\|?
```

it will capture the three variables ( or more if you have more )

Comment: this is VERY close! almost exactly what i need. Any way you can write it such that it does NOT include the "=" and the "|" symbols at the beginning and end?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a quite simple solution that will extract the variable/value like you wanted:

```
(?<variable>[^| :=\r\n]+)\s*=(?<value>[^|\r\n]+)
```

Demo+explanation: http://regex101.com/r/mC8jR2

Comment: Thank you for this but i am needing just the values AFTER the equal sign. YOUR DEMO IS SUPER COOL!!!

Comment: @ThePracticalSyde What's wrong with the regex as written? If you need the space immediately after the `=`, then change `=\s*(?<value>` to `=(?<value>\s*`.

Comment: @ThePracticalSyde: view edited post. I also agree that the demo is awesome :)

Comment: Nothing is wrong with the regular expression! I am trying to get this regular expression to work in my automation utility but it is not returning the "results" back to me that your demo is. Bare with me will i try a few iterations and see if i can come up with a solution.